# Qt 6.2: QMediaPlayer & QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt

Good day.
Has anyone tried QMediaPlayer in Qt 6.2 already?
I'm trying this code, but  Media Status always remains as "NoMedia" and no any sound :).
Full test project: https://github.com/avttrue/MediaPlayerTest

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QFile>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QMediaPlayer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QFile file("../test/Bankrobber.mp3");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        qDebug() << "File not opened";
    qDebug() << "File size:" << file.size(); // File size: 11181085

    QByteArray ba = file.readAll();
    qDebug() << "ByteArray size:" << ba.size(); // ByteArray size: 11181085

    QBuffer* buffer = new QBuffer(this);
    buffer->setData(ba);
    if(!buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        qDebug() << "Buffer not opened";
    qDebug() << "Buffer size:" << buffer->size(); // Buffer size: 11181085

    buffer->seek(qint64(0));

    auto audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(this);
    auto player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    player->setAudioOutput(audioOutput);
    audioOutput->setVolume(50);
    player->setSourceDevice(buffer);
    qDebug() << "Device:" << player->sourceDevice(); // Device: QBuffer(0x563180493020)

    QObject::connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged,
                     [=](QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)
    { qDebug() << "MediaStatus:" << player->mediaStatus() << "|" << status; });

    QObject::connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::errorOccurred,
                     [=](QMediaPlayer::Error error)
    { qDebug() << "Error:" << player->errorString() << "|" << error; });

    QObject::connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::playbackStateChanged,
                     [=](QMediaPlayer::PlaybackState state)
    { qDebug() << "PlaybackState:" << player->playbackState() << "|" << state; });

    player->play();
    qDebug() << "MediaStatus:" << player->mediaStatus(); // MediaStatus: QMediaPlayer::NoMedia
}
```

Comment: Do not edit your post since that way my answer would not make sense, nor the others.

Comment: @eyllanesc

Ok, agree, I overreacted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs points out:

> [void QMediaPlayer::setSourceDevice(QIODevice *device, const QUrl
> &sourceUrl = QUrl())](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.2/qmediaplayer.html#setSourceDevice)
>
> Sets the current source device.
>
> The media data will be read from device. **The sourceUrl can be provided
> to resolve additional information about the media, mime type etc. The
> device must be open and readable.**
>
> For macOS the device should also be seek-able.
>
> Note: This function returns immediately after recording the specified
> source of the media. It does not wait for the media to finish loading
> and does not check for errors. Listen for the mediaStatusChanged() and
> error() signals to be notified when the media is loaded, and if an
> error occurs during loading.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

QMediaPlayer does not know how to deduce the file format so it does not load it. The solution is to point out that it is an mp3:

```cpp
player->setSourceDevice(buffer, QUrl("foo.mp3"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I was just confused by this "const QUrl &sourceURL = Url()". As if this is not a required parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The function setSourceDevice() you are using isn't doing what you think?
Maybe you wanted setSource() instead?

Qt has great documentation:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaplayer.html#setSourceDevice

Even good examples:

```
player = new QMediaPlayer;
audioOutput = new QAudioOutput;
player->setAudioOutput(audioOutput);
connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), this, SLOT(positionChanged(qint64)));
player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/Users/me/Music/coolsong.mp3"));
audioOutput->setVolume(50);
player->play();
```

Ref.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaplayer.html#details

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is in a test project, I upload a file to QByteArray.
In a working project, I use a QByteArray from a database with a previously uploaded audio file.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is as variant, but i think it not good:

```
QTemporaryFile tfile;
if (!tfile.open())
     qDebug() << "TemporaryFile not opened";
 else
 {
     qDebug() << "TemporaryFile writed:" << tfile.write(ba);
     if(tfile.size() != ba.size())
         qDebug() << "TemporaryFile not complited";
     else
         player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(tfile.fileName()));
 }
```